# C# WPF Datagridview change dynamic property to type selected from combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

I would like to be able to set the type of a dynamic property "Value" of each entry in my datagrid by selecting either "int","bool" or "string" from a combo box.

The datagrid is binded to an ObservableCollection of the following class which contains the Value property:

```
public class TagIO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is the collection I am binding the datagrid's source to:

```
ObservableCollection<TagIO> InputCollection = new ObservableCollection<TagIO>();
```

How do I make the Value property a specified type from the datagridview? I was thinking to add another property called "Type" and make it a combobox column to specify the type (int, bool etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic properties in C# can lead to issues, and is generally considered bad practice unless you fall under certain cases where it's need (such as COM interop). I would personally store the value as a string regardless and then attempt `TryParse()` on it when required.

Now that you have my 2 cents, here is how you can achieve what you want.

You were correct in saying you should add a property to your class to handle the `Type`. By adding that property you can take advantage of `Convert.ChangeType` to return your dynamic.

Example:

```
 public class TagIO
 {
         //Create a private field to store your dynamic's value
         private dynamic val; 

         //Create a property to store Type
         public Type MyType{get;set;} 

         public string Name{get;set;}


         public dynamic Value
         {
             get
             {
                 //Return dynamic value as specified type
                 return Convert.ChangeType(val, MyType);
             }
             set
             {
                 //set dynamic value.
                 val = value;
             }
         }

}
```

Example Usage

```
TagIO tg = new TagIO();
tg.MyType = typeof(int);
tg.Value = 311;
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", tg.MyType.Name, tg.Value); //Int32 311
Console.ReadKey();
```